# How to get console output of Get-AdUser but also pipe it into another command?

Tags: powershell, windows-console, tee

I am trying to run a `get-aduser` command and `|` it into a `set-aduser` command, but how do I display the `get-aduser` command and also pipe it into the `set-aduser`?

Thanks

Comment: Save it to a variable. Display the variable, and then pipe the variable to set-aduser.

Comment: `Set-ADUser` has a `-PassThru` switch to see the object that was worked on.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - which may not be what the user wants to display; as I read the question - which could be clarified - the user wants to see what `Get-ADUser` returns, then modify it with `Set-ADUser`. Using `-PassThru` on `Set-ADUser` will show the modified object.

Comment: Cory, you should edit this question to clarify your intent. If you want to show the object as it is when you get it, my solution below should serve. If you want to show the object as you've modified it with `Set-ADUser`, take note of @AbrahamZinala comment above.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, based on the title and the wording in the question, I'd say the problem you've solved is the right one, but that makes it a duplicate of the linked post.

Comment: @mklement0n - yeah, and I thought of `Tee-Object` first, but didn't think to see if that question had been asked. I think I'm going to take the `Tee-Host` from the linked duplicate and add it to my General-Utilities module...

Answer (score 2):

Pipe the output of the `Get-ADUser` command to a scriptblock that displays it and also executes the `Set-ADUser` command:

```
Get-ADUser ... | ForEach-Object { $_ ; Set-ADUser $_ ... }
```

The first `$_` displays the object returned by `Get-ADUser`; the second passes it to the `Set-ADUser` command.

Comment: Nice, though for robustness as a more general pattern I suggest `$_ | Set-AdUser ...`  Worth pointing out that this won't scale well for commands that output many objects, because the per-object invocation of the target command can get expensive.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how this works, pipping to a script block like shown in the answer isn't parser error? Was this meant to be `| & { process { $_ .... } }` ? cc @mklement0 hope you can help me understand

Comment: @Santiago Oops! I think Jeff simply forgot `%` / `ForEach-Object` before the script block - an omission I didn't notice either.

Comment: thanks @mklement0 ‍♂️, thought I was going mad lol a process script block would be more memory friendly and efficient here as zett42 demonstrated in the linked answer.

Comment: Yeah, there indeed should have been a `ForEach-Object` there; not sure how I blew that one... Added.